# amqplib, checkQueue() crashing my app when error hit

Tags: javascript, node.js, amqp

I am writing a service injestor in express, to take request and pass them onto rabbit MQ.

I can't seem to get around the checkQueue() errors gracefully. everytime i hit them, my whole app crashes out with this error.

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Channel closed by server: 404 (NOT-FOUND) with message "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'asdfasdfb' in vhost '/'"
  at Channel.C.accept (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/channel.js:406:17)
  at Connection.mainAccept [as accept] (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:63:33)
  at Socket.go (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:476:48)
  at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
  at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:411:10)
  at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:405:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:157:11)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

This is the bit of AMQP code that is giving me Grief

```
.post(function(req, res) {
var promise =  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

  var queue = req.body.queue;
  if ( typeof(queue) == 'undefined' || queue.length == 0 ) return reject("No Queue Specified");

  // need to add VALID JSON CHECK
  var message = req.body.message;
  if ( typeof(message) == 'undefined' || message.length == 0 ) reject("No Message Specified");

  // select the Awknoledgement of the queue.
  var noAck = req.body.ack || true;

  // select the durabiltiy of the queue. Custing issues in the below if different hten when created.
  var durableOpt = req.body.durable || false;

  var assertOpt = {durable: durableOpt};

  var sendOptions = {
    noAck: noAck,
    contentType: 'application/json' };

  amqp.connect( process.env.QUEUE_HOST , function(err, conn) {

    if (err) return reject(err);

    conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      var check = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        ch.checkQueue(queue, function(err,ok){
          if (err != null){
            return reject(err);
          } else {
            return resolve(true);
          }
        })
      })

      var assert = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        ch.assertQueue( queue , assertOpt, function(err,ok){
          if (err != null){
            return reject(err);
          } else {
            return resolve(true);
          }
        })
      })

      Promise.all( [ check , assert ] ).then(function( values ){

        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i] !== true){
            reject(values[i])
          }
        }

        if( ch.sendToQueue(queue, new Buffer( JSON.stringify( message ) ) , sendOptions) == true){
          return resolve('message added');
        }

      }) // end Promise.all
    }) // end conn.createChannel
  }) // end amqp.connect
}) // end of promise.

promise.then(
function(response){
  res.status(200).json(response);
},
function( error ){
  res.status(400).json(error);
})
})
```

If i ever hit that error in checkQueue, or of i actually have errors in AssertQueue. It always crashes out with the error described above. Channel always closes, and get an events.js:141 error. is there any way to keep errors in calls from killing my channel? or do i need to reconnect it up on the fly when errors occur?

Comment: Are you sure, that you cant call 

if (err) return reject(err); -in second row outside of promise?

Comment: sorry i am not sure where you are taling about here...

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was causing the problem... conn was throwing an error that i wasn't catching 'properly' I tried a standard try/catch but it didn't like that either.

After digging through the [docs](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#model_events) for a while i found it under "events" i guess that makes sense, but it would be nice to have labeled error handling.

```
conn.on('error', function(handle){
  reject(handle);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but seems that you call `return reject(err);` outside of promise.

Try this code

```html
amqp.connect( process.env.QUEUE_HOST , function(err, conn) {

  if (err) return console.log(err);

  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {

    if (err) return console.log(err);

    var check = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      <<< SPECIFICALLY THIS >>>
      ch.checkQueue(queue, function(err,ok){
        if (err != null){
          return reject(err);
        } else{
          return resolve(true);
        }
      })
    })

    var assert = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      <<< AND THIS >>>
      ch.assertQueue( queue , assertOpt, function(err,ok){
        if (err != null){
          return reject(err);
        } else {
          return resolve(true);
        }
      });
    })

    Promise.all( [check,assert] ).then(function(values){
      console.log(values);
      if( ch.sendToQueue(queue, new Buffer( JSON.stringify( message ) ) , sendOptions) == true){
        return resolve('message added');
      }
    })

  });
})
```

Comment: Ah, sorry i see what oyu meant above. Yeah i already, updated that and still same error. I think problem is in the AMQP protocol, where it closes out my connection when the server errors. So i need to somehow catch that close and reopen the connection before any mroe of my code runs.

Comment: Ah sorry this is not the entire code snippet there is more logic above, let me post the whol ething here for you. its specifically the code given that is causeing the isues

Comment: Updated original post with full expres .post() method.